# R Error trying to plot contingency table as side by side bar plot

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having an issue when creating a dataframe to use to plot my contingency table values (minus sums). Here is the current contingency table (as a dataframe):

```
              Nauseau_Y         Nauseau_N    Sum
Anesthesia_A         26                13    39
Anesthesia_A         10                23    33
Sum                  36                36    72
```

I am trying to  make a side-by-side bar graph showing the nausea (Yes vs No) on the horizontal axis and color-coded bars to indicate the type of anesthetic. Here is what I have to create the plot data

```
plotdata=data.frame("Anesthesia_Type"=c("Anesthesia A","Anesthesia B"),
                    "Anesthesia A"=c(anes_df$Nauseau_Y[1],anes_df$Nauseau_Y[2]),
                    "Anesthesia B"=c(anes_df$Nauseau_N[1],anes_df$Nauseau_N[2]),
                    row.names = c("st1","st2"))
```

and I get the error:

```
Error in data.frame(Anesthesia_Type = c("Anesthesia A", "Anesthesia B"), : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0
```

So the question is how do I create the dataframe to plot it the way I want it?

Comment: you dont need quote marks around your new variable names in `data.frame()` also it works for me, so make sure your data is saved as `anes_df`. Also your title is a little missleading. You are not having this error while trying to plot, you are having an error creating a dataframe.

Comment: can you do dput(anes_df) and paste the output as part of your post? I suspect it might not be a data.frame. If I tried what you have, it works for me. Also note that your row names for anes_df is duplicated, which should not be the case, R will correct this, hence my reason for asking for dput()